# How do I write a specific column in another line pug (dynamic html)

Tags: html, css, pug

## The problem

I'm trying to build a dynamic table using pug language
I have something like this:

[image: Before]

And then I wish to transform to this:

[image: After]

### What I tried

So far, I tried to have nested `tr()`, with the "Outside" one with a `ng-repeat`, but I can't unlink the columns [Name, Surname, Address, Age] and [Status] to put this last one on another line. What do I need to do? change some CSS property or fix the nested `tr` ?

### Code for example

```
tbody(class="...")

    each row in filter.table.data

        tr
            
            td( class="cursor-pointer" ) 
                div(class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;width:110px")
                    button(...) 
                        span(class="fa fa-search")
                    button(...) 
                        span(class="fa fa-user")
                    button(...) 
                        span(class="fa fa-power-off")
                        
            
            td(ng-repeat="column in filter.table.columns track by $index" ng-if="row.status == 7801" style="opacity:1")
                span(ng-if="!($index == 9)") {{ row[column.binding] }}
            td(ng-repeat="column in filter.table.columns track by $index" ng-if="row.status == 7802" style="opacity:0.4")
                span(ng-if="!($index == 9)") {{ row[column.binding] }}
        
        tr
            td
                table(class="table table-striped table-bordered" dt-options="dtOptions" style="display:inline")
                    thead(style="font-size:10px")
                        tr
                            th(style="text-align:center") {{ filter.table.columns[9].label }}

                    tbody(...)
                        tr
                            td(ng-if="row.status == 7801" style="opacity:1")
                                span(class="modal-title" ng-click="modals.text.open(row)") {{ row[filter.table.columns[9].binding] }}
                            td(ng-if="row.status == 7802" style="opacity:0.4")
                                span(class="modal-title" ng-click="modals.text.open(row)") {{ row[filter.table.columns[9].binding] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what backend technology you are using. Assuming it is Node.js, and the `data` passed to the Pug script is an array like:

```
const data = [
  { name: "name 1", surname: "surname 2", address: "address 1", age: "age 1", status: "status 1" },
  { name: "name 2", surname: "surname 2", address: "address 2", age: "age 2", status: "status 2" },
  { name: "name 3", surname: "surname 3", address: "address 3", age: "age 3", status: "status 3" }
];
```

Then Pug script:

```
p Odd Table
table(border="1")
  each row in data 
    tr 
      td Name 
      td Surname 
      td Address 
      td Age 
    tr 
      td=row.name 
      td=row.surname 
      td=row.address 
      td=row.age 
    tr 
      td(colspan="4") Status
    tr 
      td(colspan="4" style="text-align:center")=row.status
```

will result in:

[image]

Comment: Because I have an ```tr(ng-repeat="row in filter.table.data")``` on the tbody, if  I try to add one more tr to put the status, I get the error: "DataTables warning: table id=tableOne - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0"

Comment: What if you drop that `ng-repeat` attribute?

Comment: I don't know why, but if I remove the ```ng-repeat``` and put ```each row in filter.table.data``` the page just don't load. The problem is that I need to follow the pattern of this .pug because I didn't create this file, but I need to fix this

Comment: I added the code the I made trying to use the solution of @Old-Geezer